# Есть ли утечка памяти в коде

Tags: c++

Есть участок кода в программе:

```
while (true) {
  char value[len+1];
  //какие-то операции с переменной value
}
```

Есть ли тут утечка памяти, если не обнулять переменную `value` в конце операций цикла?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет.
Ваш массив `value` относится к классу автоматической памяти. Он будет уничтожен без вашего участия.

Теперь о том, когда утечки могут возникать.
Утечки памяти могут появиться когда вы начинаете выделять память вручную:

```
char *value = new char[len+1];
```

В моем примере объявлена переменная `value` типа "указатель на `char`". Эта переменная указывает на участок памяти, за освобождение которого отвечаете вы.

Чтобы утечки не было, нужно удалить то, на что указывает `value`:

```
delete[] value;
```

Таким образом код примет такой вид:

```
void foo(int len){
    char *value = new char[len+1];
    //...
    delete[] value;
}
```

**PS**: Кстати, ваш код примерно так и должен выглядеть. Потому что в С++ размер массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции. Если ваш компилятор прожевал `char value[len+1]`, то это не значит что другой сделает то же самое.

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно использовать new, но пока необходимо использовать такой кусок кода)

Comment: "Он будет уничтожен без вашего участия." -  Это когда будет сделано? После повторного объявления char той же самой переменой или завершению функции?

Comment: @nerik, ну, если len где-то выше объявлена как `const int len`, то ничего криминального. Если нет, то вас учат ошибкам. А вообще вам нужно использовать `std::vector`. Вы, наверно, до этого еще не дошли, это так, на будущее.

Comment: @nerik, а вы попробуйте объявить ту же самую переменную в той-же области видимости:). Компилятор заказывает память под автоматические переменные при входе в функцию и освобождает при выходе.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, это не ошибка, строго говоря. Это просто расширение компилятора.

Comment: @ixSci, ну да, согласен, на счет ошибки это я погорячился. Правильнее было бы сказать "учат писать непереносимый код"

Answer (score 4):

Здесь не происходит динамическое выделение памяти, поэтому ни о какой утечке не может быть и речи. Хотя `char value[len+1]` будет работать только на gcc.

Comment: Так как объявления `len` не представлено, говорить о VLA преждевременно. Это вполне может быть константа времени компиляции.

Answer (score 1):

Помню как то препода спрашивал "стоит ли выносить объявления переменных перед циклом" препод сказал что не нужно, не помню аргументировал ли.

Во всех кодах которые пишут умны люди (большие корпорации) тоже видно что переменные объявляться в теле цикла.

Моя логика говорит: зачем каждый раз выделять область памяти, это же тоже занимает какое то время для машины, но делаю как все))

Возможно "умные" компиляторы, все новые переменные в цикле как то сами оптимизируют код, не знаю.

Comment: Память для локальных переменных "выделяется" при входе в функцию. Для всех разом, одной машинной командой; и не важно, в цикле они объявляются или нет.

Comment: Так-то ресурсы программы это не только память. Если у вас есть сложный объект, который в конструкторе подключается к бд, читает файл или устанавливает соединение по сети, а в деструкторе делает обратные операции, то лучше вынести его из цикла. [Пример](http://cpp.sh/66fj)